# WSO2 error HTTP Status 500

Tags: java, wso2, wso2-iot

I have a problem on my EMM virtual machine.

When I go to my console an error appears, as the screen shows
I think I have done all the previous tasks correctly, but only the people who do not work are not mistaken, so the error can come from the previous steps.

[image: Error 500]

I'm running Windows Server 2008 64-bit

I have Java JDK 8 update 121

I have the latest version of WSO2 EMM

I'm logged in admin

Comment: could you paste the stacktrace error?

Comment: Hello cralfaro, i dont know what is a stacktrace, but if you talk about the error text : An error has occurred!
HTTP Status - 500
Org.jaggerjys.scriptengine.exceptions ScriptExeption: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer SSL hostname failure validation for name: our IP address

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the SSL certificate available in wso2carbon.jks in set to localhost not to the ip address. You can simply navigate to the emm server by clicking on the WSO2 logo.
and you can create a self singed SSL certificate to the ip address and replace the current cert in order to prevent this screen.